# Facebook Open Graph scraper does not pass request parameters

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

If I use FB Debug tool to check my URL which looks like www.example.com/dir/index.php?a=b the `index.php` script does not receive `a=b` in any of the request variables. If I update returned tags, I can instantly see the change in scraped data, but the `_REQUEST` variable stays empty.